# When should an object be put in a "resting" state for physics?

Tags: c++, algorithm, physics, game-physics

When should an object to put in a "resting" state for physics?

I have read in the past that for physics, after a certain values (such as velocity) hit a very small range that the object should be put in a "resting" state. How should this be done and when should it be done? Or, is this just a bad technique?

From what I recall from my reading some time ago, there was a potential scenario when it was determined there would be a collision and the collision time was some extraordinarily small value (such as 0.00001f). However, this seems like it could present a false positive, is this true?

Comment: What do you mean by "resting" state? Do you mean a disabling the object if there are no nearby moving objects? Or do you mean when to use resting contacts vs. impact contacts? Or something else?

Comment: By "resting" I mean they are sort of "disabled" where the object wouldn't be a dynamic object, but rather seem like a static object (unless of course, a future force is acted upon it). I am however, not familiar with "esting contacts vs. impact contacts". Would you be able to point me to a research point so I could read up on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather vague term and it totally depends on the requirements of your physics simulation. That said, it can be a very efficient optimization to let objects 'rest' if you *know it won't hurt*.

Many physics engines have a so called "freezing" state, which simply means they won't process frozen bodies until certain conditions occur (or not at all). "Resting" may also mean that dynamic bodies are (with velocity approaching zero) treated as static bodies, which are usually faster since no spatial data structures need to be updated.

> > How should this be done and when should it be done?

When implementing this, you'll almost certainly need to do some experimenting to tweak the parameters, don't expect it to work immediately.

"How" is a question that cannot be answered without further details (i.e. which physics engine, framework, own development ...?).

Comment: I am using my own physics engine (which I have been attempting to develop as an exercise/fun project). From what it seems that you said, I should put them in "resting" when the velocity is approaching zero. Is there any othertime?

Comment: A possible example would be very non-local objects. If you have a very large world, it may not be possible to omit physics updates for large parts of the game "universe" so tat the player never notices the difference. To decide what can be frozen and what not is a very difficult question to which there is no easy solution as all depends on your scenario.